# What network does GPSI evaluate mobile on? Is it 3g or 4g?

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

All our customers are based in America. So does google page speed insights test the "mobile" on 3g n/w?

If yes, is there a way to tell Google to only care about speeds above 4g only for the test?

Answer (score 2):

It tests with the following throttling:

**Latency:** 150ms

**Throughput:** 1.6Mbps down / 750 Kbps up.

Which is roughly equivalent to the slowest 25% of 4G and highest 25% of 3G speeds.

You can [find out more about this here along with CPU throttling speeds.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md)